# Where does my chain breaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, es6-class, es6-modules

Im goinig to build an "Employee Managment System" for the 5th time for practice purposes. each time I practice diffrent way of coding (Hopefully in time I'd be good at it).

later on I'll add a form with some text inputs and a button which will register the new us Employee and show it in a list.

but this time I am on doing this code with a "Web App" orientationish.
I want to create all my HTML through mostly Javascript.
I created a template inside `class Item` which will eventually inject some html to `index.html`

in this system I have **3 types/classes of employees**:

1. Teacher
2. Developer
3. CEO

Each employee type has diffrent methods.
But there are 2 methods that all types of employee get.
`sayHello()` and `checkIn()`. that thanks to `class Employee` which all the other types inherit from.

Anyway..

in **Item.js** I wanted a render function to be broken into two smaller functions:

1. **renderContainer()** - a template for creating a parent-container for the user details.
2. **renderDetails()** -  a template for the user details.

I tried debbuging it using console.log in those places where i wanted to check the returned value. I'm not that familliar yet with the debugger and its pros.

Can you tell whats wrong with my code?
What's wrong with this line ?         `this.container.find(".employee").html($details);`

and Why doesn't it's value being passed properly to `renderContainer()` where its being called on ?

The git repository: 
https://github.com/ueeieiie/ems3

**script.js** file:

```
require('../styles/styles.scss');

import Employee from './Employee.js';
import Teacher from './Teacher.js';
import Developer from './Developer.js';
import CEO from './CEO.js';
import Item from './Item.js';

var $ = require('jquery');

// udi
var udi = new CEO("Udi", "Cinephile", "CEO");
var udiItem = new Item(udi);
udiItem.renderContainer();

// rani
var rani = new Developer("rani", "Jaggling", "Developer");
var raniItem = new Item(rani);
raniItem.renderContainer();
```

**CEO.js** file:

```
import Employee from './Employee.js';

export default class CEO extends Employee {
    constructor(name, skill, title){
        super(name, skill, title="CEO")
    }
    fireEveryone(){
        console.log(this.name + " has fired EVERYONE!");
    }
}
```

**Developer.js** file:

```
import Employee from './Employee.js';

export default class Developer extends Employee {
    constructor(name, skill, title){
        super(name, skill, title="Developer");
    }
    pushCode(){
        console.log(this.name + " has pushed some code.");
    }
}
```

**Employee.js** file:

```
export default class Employee {
    constructor(name, skill, title){
        this.name = name;
        this.skill = skill;
        this.title = title;
    }

    sayHello(){
        console.log(this.name + " said hello");
    }

    checkIn(){
        console.log(new Date());
    }
}
```

**Item.js** file:

```
var id = 0;
var $ = require('jquery');

export default class Item{
    constructor(user){
        this.id = this.getId();
        this.name = user.name;
        this.skill = user.skill;
        this.title = user.title;
    }

    renderContainer(){
        var $container = $(`
            <dl class="employee">

            </dl>
        `);

        this.container = $container;

        this.renderDetails();
        $('.content').append($container);

    }

    renderDetails(){
        var $details = $(`

        <p>
            <dt>ID: </dt>
            <dd>${this.id}</dd>
        </p>
        <p>
            <dt>Name: </dt>
            <dd>${this.name}</dd>
        </p>
        <p>
            <dt>Skill: </dt>
            <dd>${this.skill}</dd>
        </p>
        <p>
            <dt>Title: </dt>
            <dd>${this.title}</dd>
        </p>

        `);
        this.container.find(".employee").html($details);
        // $('.content').append($details);  //works fine with no need of renderContainer()
    }

    getId(){
        return id++;
    }
}
```

**index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- template comes here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question that "why doesn't it work"?  Please describe what exactly happens when you run your code and what you were expecting that is different than what actually does happen.  And, describe when debugging steps you took and what you learned in doing that debugging (console.log statements, breakpoints, etc...).

Comment: yes, thank you, I'll be more specific and update

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell whats wrong with my code? What's wrong with this line
>   `this.container.find(".employee").html($details);` ?

`this.container` is this jQuery object:

```
    $(`
        <dl class="employee">

        </dl>
    `);
```

When you call `.find()` on that, it searches inside the `<dl>` for `.employee` because `.find()` searches the descendants only.   But, there is no `.employee` inside the `<dl>` object so it returns an empty jQuery object which calling `.html()` on then does nothing to.  The `.employee` you want to target is already the parent, not a descendant.

Here's what the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/find/) says for `.find()`:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

You can fix that code by changing from this:

```
this.container.find(".employee").html($details);
```

to this:

```
this.container.html($details);
```

Or, if you want the ability for the code to handle a template where .employee is either the parent or a descendant, you could test for it being the parent:

```
if (this.container.is(".employee") {
    this.container.html($details);
} else {
    this.container.find(".employee").html($details);
}
```